# ValueError: too many values to unpack when using apply to return multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I am using apply function to return 2 new columns, and then I got an error, not sure what is wrong? Thanks for your help.

```
def calc_test(row):

    a=row['col1']+row['col2']
    b=row['col1']/row['col2']

    return (a,b)

df_test_dict={'col1':[1,2,3,4,5],'col2':[10,20,30,40,50]}
df_test=pd.DataFrame(df_test_dict)
df_test

    col1    col2
0   1   10
1   2   20
2   3   30
3   4   40
4   5   50
```

```
df_test['a'],df_test['b']=df_test.apply(lambda row:calc_test(row),axis=1)
df_test

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Temp\1/ipykernel_12160/3210544870.py in <module>
      2 df_test=pd.DataFrame(df_test_dict)
      3 
----> 4 df_test['a'],df_test['b']=df_test.apply(lambda row:calc_test(row),axis=1)
      5 df_test

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` doesn't return two new columns, it returns one series (column) with cells being a tuple. You can try:

```
df_test[['a','b']] = pd.DataFrame(df_test.apply(lambda row:calc_test(row),axis=1).tolist())
```

Comment: oh yeah, Quang, yes it works. Good to know that. Thank you! I appreicate it

Comment: Hi Quang, for simple example, it works, for my real data, if I do df_test[['a','b']] = pd.DataFrame(), the column a and b have value of NaN. if I do df_1=pd.DataFrame(), then df_1 have all the value I needed. so I am confused why df_test[['a','b']] = pd.DataFrame() doesn't work for my real case. only difference is df_test has index column. Any insight? Thanks

Comment: I think the reason it does work fro my real case is because the original dataframe has index, for this case, any alternative solution?

Comment: I change the code above to include index and it doesn't. could you please hep me with anothe resolution? Thanks

Comment: ok, I create a new ticker for this differnet case.

Comment: @roudan add `index=df_test.index` into `pd.DataFrame(...,)`